# Click events for each object in List View - Android

Tags: android

I have the following List View

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liv1);

    List<Room> livarray = new ArrayList<Room>();

    livarray.add(new Room(R.drawable.room, "Meeting Room 1", "Small", "Yes"));
    livarray.add(new Room(R.drawable.room, "IT Floor", "Large", "Yes"));
    livarray.add(new Room(R.drawable.room, "Data Innovations Room", "Medium", "No"));
    livarray.add(new Room(R.drawable.room, "Batman Room", "Large", "No"));
    livarray.add(new Room(R.drawable.room, "Brainstorming Room", "Small", "No"));
    livarray.add(new Room(R.drawable.room, "Room 1408", "Expanding", "No"));

    ListView listViewRooms = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liv1);

    ListRoomsAdapter adapter = new ListRoomsAdapter(this, livarray);

    listViewRooms.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

How would I have a specific onClick handler for each object in the list?

Comment: By "object" do you mean a listitem? Or anything inside an item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` and then define operations for every element in your adapter like that:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Room item = livarray.get(position);
            switch(position){
                case item ...
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `onItemClickListener` to your ListView. You can then, in your on click method, retrieve your room using `livarray.get(position)`.

You could add a runnable to your Room object or whereever you want and use it at this place...

Answer (score 1):

```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         Room mRoom=  livarray.get(position).

        });
```